# Fantasy story with 4 guardians and 1 master living in the capital

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm looking for a book I read about 10 years ago.
Unfortunately, I don't know how old the book was at the time. It was borrowed from a library so the state of the book is a very bad indicator, that being said I am certain that is was not brand new at the time. Could be anything from 2 to 10 years older [ca. 1998-2006].
The target audience is probably young-adult, but I wouldn't classify it as a typical one at that.

I can't remember much from the book, but there are 4 guardians and a master living in the capital. Their job is to keep the world in balance. I think this is ruined by a woman who kills the guardians and seduces the master.

The only other thing I remember is that the protagonist learns to use his magic while raking leaves because the color of them reminds him of fire, he then accidentally sets the pile of leaves on fire.

Comment: You have a good start here, can you check [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? You say you read it when you was younger, when was that? Was the book new then? Also nice job on spotting the usage guidance for the genre tag!

Comment: Didn't consider the fact that only I know what "when I was younger" refers to. Thanks for pointing me in direction of the guide

Comment: the fact that you were younger is not helping us very much, unless you can tell us if the book was aimed at a younger audience (Children, teens) or an 'adult' novel.

Comment: @Trish Younger in most story id questions usually means I read it when I was young not that the book was aimed at young audiences (though it may or may not be). Nice to try and clarify but just letting you know.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot which is exactly what I was trying to get from OP

Comment: @Trish It is much appreciated, feedback is the only way to improve upon the question